# I changed the web service declaration and then wsimport says that I have a repeated message

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

I had a Web service method working fine on Tomcat as deployed by Netbeans 6.8. Then I had to add a new parameter for the same method so I erased the method and then added a new one with the same name but different parameters.

After that, ws-import keeps on telling me that I have duplicated messages for such method, and  if I remove the new one, the WSDL will still show me the old one with the old parameter list.

How do I get rid of the old one?

thanks in advance.

Comment: now it is working, but still have no idea how did it got screwed in the first place, and back on woking on the second.
Any help will be appreciated in order to understand this kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit embarrasing. It happened to me again but then I realized I hadn't restart my Tomcat server. It worked.

Thanks anyway.